Collect exceptions from multiple statements into one
I am writing a manager to handle sending emails using the javax.mail library. When building a Message, I'm calling the set methods a few times using values provided by the caller of my method:
// MailBuilder: builder class for containing various email-related values
public void sendEmails(MailBuilder mailBuilder) {
  Message msg = new SMTPMessage(Session.getInstance(presetProperties));
  
  try {
    msg.setContent(mailBuilder.body);
    msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, mailBuilder.to);
    msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, mailBuilder.cc);
    msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, mailBuilder.bcc);
    msg.setSubject(mailBuilder.subject);
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed email", e);
  }

  // ...send email
}

If any of the set methods throw an exception, I want to wrap it in an IllegalArgumentException to send up to the caller. However, if I wrap all of them in one try block, if setContent throws an exception, the other methods will not be called, and any errors that might have occurred with those methods as well will not get communicated to the caller. I know I can chain together try-catch blocks like this to collect possible exceptions as suppressed, but it's very clunky:
MessagingException collectedExceptions = null;
try {
  msg.setContent(mailBuilder.body)
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  if (collectedExceptions == null) collectedExceptions = e;
  else collectedExceptions.addSuppressed(e);
}

try {
  msg.setSubject(mailBuilder.subject);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  if (collectedExceptions == null) collectedExceptions = e;
  else collectedExceptions.addSuppressed(e);
}

// repeat for other methods

if (collectedExceptions != null) throw collectedExceptions;

Is there a cleaner way to use multiple methods, and only throw at the end of any number of them threw an exception?

@ElliottFrisch Message is a part of the javax.mail library, so I can't change Message.setSubject() to not throw an exception. Should I clarify that by showing the imports in the code snippet?

Cardinal System's answer was the right direction that I needed, I made a few tweaks and expansions to encapsulate it in one handler:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ExceptionCollector<E extends Exception> {
  private final List<E> thrown = new ArrayList<>();
  private final AtomicInteger calls = new AtomicInteger(0);

  // Will usually call this like 
  // ExceptionCollector.<IllegalArgumentException>begin()
  public static <E extends Exception> ExceptionCollector<E> begin() {
    return new ExceptionCollector<>();
  }

  // alternate static constructor for specifying exception type
  // ExceptionCollector.collect(IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public static <E extends Exception> ExceptionCollector<E> collect(Class<E> exceptionClass) {
    return new ExceptionCollector<>();
  }

  private ExceptionCollector() {}

  // OverlyBroadCatchBlock: Intellij warning for a catch block catching exceptions more broad than what is thrown in the block, like an Exception catch for a method that throws IOException
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "OverlyBroadCatchBlock" })
  public ExceptionCollector<E> attempt(ThrowingRunnable<? extends E> runnable) {
    calls.incrementAndGet();
    try {
      runnable.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      thrown.add((E) e);
    }
    return this;
  }
  
  public void throwIfAny() throws E {
    Optional<E> result = thrown.stream.reduce((base, e) -> {
      base.addSuppressed(e);
      return base;
    });
    if (result.isPresent()) throw result.get();
  }

  // throws if every attempt threw, otherwise returns a list of exceptions thrown
  public List<E> throwIfAll() throws E {
    throwIfAllElse(l -> {});
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(thrown);
  }

  // throws if every attempt threw, otherwise provides a list of exceptions thrown to the provided consumer
  public void throwIfAllElse(ThrowingConsumer<? super List<? extends E>, ? extends X> partialExceptionConsumer) throws E, X {
    if (calls.get() != thrown.size()) {
      partialExceptionConsumer.accept(Collections.unmodifiableList(thrown));
      return;
    }
    throwIfAny();
  }
}

Example use for the problem in my question:
try {
  ExceptionCollector.collect(MessagingException.class)
    .attempt(() -> msg.setContent(mailBuilder.body))
    .attempt(() -> msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, mailBuilder.to))
    .attempt(() -> msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, mailBuilder.cc))
    .attempt(() -> msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, mailBuilder.bcc))
    .attempt(() -> msg.setSubject(mailBuilder.subject))
    .throwIfAny();
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid email", e);
}


I don't know why you would need to call every method, even if one fails...
As for your question, it seems that your concern is too much boilerplate. One solution is to delegate your try-catch to another method and pass it a list to collect the exceptions.
Here's an example:
public void sendEmails(MailBuilder mailBuilder) {
    Message msg = new SMTPMessage(Session.getInstance(presetProperties));

    List<MessagingException> exceptions = new ArrayList<MessagingException>(5);
    tryInvoke(() -> msg.setContent(mailBuilder.body), exceptions);
    tryInvoke(() -> msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, mailBuilder.to), exceptions);
    tryInvoke(() -> msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, mailBuilder.cc), exceptions);
    tryInvoke(() -> msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.BCC, mailBuilder.bcc), exceptions);
    tryInvoke(() -> msg.setSubject(mailBuilder.subject), exceptions);

    if (!exceptions.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                exceptions.stream().map(Throwable::getMessage).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E extends Throwable> void tryInvoke(ThrowingRunnable<E> callable, Collection<E> exceptions) {
    try {
        callable.run();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        exceptions.add((E) e);
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingRunnable<E extends Throwable> {
    void run() throws E;
}


The goal with calling every method is to communicate to the caller as much information as possible. setSubject throwing an exception does not prevent setRecipient from functioning normally. If the caller of my method is providing incorrect arguments to both (say they passed an empty subject and an invalid email), I want to throw an exception that has a message communicating that both arguments were incorrect, instead of whichever method threw an exception first. Some of this could probably be handled in the builder validating its fields, but these methods still throw their exceptions

I'd use separate methods for that, or some other scheme.  Your basic problem is that you're calling ten things in a row and then complaining that you can't tell which one failed.  It's a design issue, not a code issue.
